# What is the proper way to let threads print out sequentially using join

Tags: java, multithreading, join

I am curious about how to let the threads print out sequentially using `join()`.(Any other ways are also welcome.) For example, I have the code as following:

```
private static class LittleThread implements Runnable {
    int val;
    public LittleThread(int i) {
        val = i;
    }
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Thread " + val + " finished.");
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        new Thread(new LittleThread(i)).start();
    }
}
```

I am wondering, how do we do with this code, to make the `main()` prints sequentially:

> Thread 1 finished.
>   Thread 2 finished.
>   Thread 3 finished.
>   ...

Comment: "run threads sequentially" - that's kind of missing the point.

Comment: How do you put in a screw with a hammer? You don't. (And why would you want to run threads sequentially? Why does it always seem that the first thing everyone wants to do with threads is to make them completely useless?)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I agree. But this is a interview question being asked. I think the interviewer just wanted to make sure the candidates know how multithreads work and whether you know how to use some Thread functions to making the code shown above work. More of testing the multithreading concept.

Comment: Then I gave the right answer to the interview question -- you don't do that because it doesn't make sense. Most interview questions are looking for how you reason about a question. When asked how to do something you would never do, you should say you would never do that and explain why! If the interview question is "how do you use a jackhammer to get demons out of someone's head", the answer isn't about how to hold the jackhammer!

Comment: The easiest change to this code would be to use `run()` instead of `start()`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Well, someone might want to (say) compile a number of files in parallel, but not interleave the output of individual compile invocations.  The OP only asked for the output of the threads to be sequential, not the execution of the threads.  Not entirely useless.

Comment: @AJNeufeld And you would use `join` to do that?

Answer (score 1):

To make a number of `Runnable` objects, executed in a separate `Thread`, execute sequentially, you should use the single thread [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        executor.submit(new LittleThread(i));
    }

    executor.shutdown();
}
```

The `ExecutorService` is responsible for proper management of the `Thread` objects (ok, all one of them in this case) ... creating them (it) as needed, and terminating them by calling `join` (as the service is shutdown).